# ¿Como debuggear Unit Tests usando Intellij IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Creé un archivo con un único *test* pero no consigo depurarlo, me marca error en otras clases a las cuales no hago siquiera referencia.

Cuando creé el *unit tests* me pidió configurar un *JDK* para lo cual elegí:

> Information: Using **javac 1.8.0_111** to compile java sources.

Comment: usas jUnit en tú projecto?

Comment: Debes marcar tu archivo de tests en intelliJ. Click en el archivo con la tecla derecha, y entonces marcá el archivo como un archivo de tests.

Comment: Por favor comparte la estructura de carpetas de tu vista de proyecto, algo me dice que agregaste tus clases de prueba en la carpeta equivocada

Comment: otra opción es que no tengas tu JDK y solo un JRE

Comment: Problema típico es que la carpeta de test/java no está marcada como tal. En IntelliJ, verás que está de color verde. Además, verifica que puedas dar click derecho a esa carpeta y "Run Tests in <tu nombre de proyecto>". Con todo eso, ya puedes colocar un punto de interrupción a tu test y debuggear.

Comment: En realidad lo que creo que ocurre aquí, es que IntelliJ antes de ejecutar cualquier cosa, siempre quiere compilar todas las clases detodo el proyecto, incluso aunque no tengan ninguna referencia desde el unit test.
Entonces lo que tienes que asegurarte es que no tengas errores de compilación en ninguna de tus clases, sin importar si se usan en el test o no.

Answer (score 1):

Con respecto al mensaje :

> Information: Using javac 1.8.0_111 to compile java sources.

este es provocado porque tu IDE esta configurada para usar una versión diferente a la que trata de usar para compilar que es 1.8, probablemente tu IDE esta configurado con Java 1.7

Para cambiarlo ve a :

`Settings` > `Build, Execution, Deployment` > `Compiler` > `Java Compiler` y especifica la versión del compilador.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Usando IntelliJ Idea, para agregar una prueba unitaria, selecciona la clase a probar y mediante la secuencia <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> se abrirá un menú contextual en el cual debes seleccionar "Create Test".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí requerirá seleccionar los métodos a los cuales deseas asignarle una prueba:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Revisar:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-unit-tests.html

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/create-tests.html